# Animation lag due to mix-blend-mode property in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, mix-blend-mode

If you launch Chrome and check my fiddle in fullscreen mode, you'll see that the animations are laggy. The div lags a little while sliding down and the text lags a little while sliding up. If you resize the browser to be smaller the animations will play fine. Also my animations play fine in Safari.

If you delete the `.light-leaks` class that contains the `mix-blend-mode` property, the animations will run fine.

What is the problem? Thanks.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brewpixels/cmmt49ac/show/)
[fiddle in fullscreen mode](https://jsfiddle.net/brewpixels/cmmt49ac/show/)

Answer (score 0):

I had to apply the `mix-blend-mode` property after the animations were done running too avoid the lag. I did it with javascript.

```
$(".light-leaks").hide();

    setTimeout(function() {

        $(".light-leaks").fadeIn(2500);

     }, 7000);
```